# Generalizing a monadic expression over a list of items

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a monadic function that helps translating values of type Expr to Term's. The signature is

`fromDM :: (Name -> CompilerM Term) -> Expr -> CompilerM Term`

I have trouble treating one case in general. I can write down implementations for every individual solution

```
import Control.Monad.State

type CompilerM = State Incr

newtype Incr = Incr Int deriving (Show)

generateNameM :: CompilerM Name
generateNameM = state $ \i ->
  let Incr y = i
      j      = (+1) y
  in  (Name j, Incr j)

data Expr = Tuple [Expr]
data Name = Name Int
data Term = Let Name [Name] Term

fromDM :: (Name -> CompilerM Term) -> Expr -> CompilerM Term
fromDM k expr = case expr of
  Tuple [e1, e2]         -> do
    x  <- generateNameM
    t' <- k x
    fromDM (\z1 -> fromDM (\z2 -> pure $ Let x [z1, z2] t') e2) e1

  Tuple [e1, e2, e3]     -> do
    x  <- generateNameM
    t' <- k x
    fromDM (\z1 -> fromDM (\z2 -> fromDM (\z3 -> pure $ Let x [z1, z2, z3] t') e3) e2) e1

  Tuple [e1, e2, e3, e4] -> do
    x  <- generateNameM
    t' <- k x
    fromDM (\z1 -> fromDM (\z2 -> fromDM (\z3 -> fromDM (\z4 -> return $ Let x [z1, z2, z3, z4] t') e4) e3) e2) e1
```

Now I want to substitute this with a general rule, i.e. `Tuple es`. I feel this should be doable with either `foldlM` or `foldrM`. Yet I am kind of stuck on how to do this. So, how do I write a general rule for this transformation that works on an arbitrary list of expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to chain functions like withCString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379984/is-there-a-way-to-chain-functions-like-withcstring)

Comment: How is that question a duplicate? I unfortunately cannot map my question to the question or answers over there.

Comment: More information about the types involved would be useful.

Comment: It seems that you are having trouble composing your `fromDM` function calls because you have to nest the callbacks that handle the sub-results. It's the same pattern as composing `withCString` etc., by turning the nesting structure inside-out via `Cont`.

Comment: @data_hope I agree that the remarks are opaque so far, and the the question is in no sense a duplicate. But ContT is the right idea. Note that  `\e -> ContT (flip fromDM e) :: Expr -> ContT Term CompilerM Name` if I have the order right. It is hard to get a handle on it with so little source.

Comment: Alright, I updated the snippet so that it is at least a compilable self-contained piece of code. I suppose that one could find a solution to generalize that pattern.

I will also have a look at `Cont`/`ContT`.

Comment: @data_hope This is the idea http://sprunge.us/KQWc

Comment: @Michael thank you, it is really neat (and Cont seems to be a very useful monad).

Comment: @data_hope I can't tell what else is going on, so maybe this is wrong, but things like `fromDM` might be put entirely in `ContT` See this http://sprunge.us/gZbQ We might even write `type Compiler a = ContT Term (State Incr) a`

Comment: @Michael Having a closer look at http://sprunge.us/gZbQ , indeed I think `type Compiler = ContT Term (State Incr)` was applicable with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I don't know much about `Cont`, so let me outline my thought process when I approached this question. The first thing I wanted to do was to pull out only the bits of code that depend on the contents of the `Tuple`, thus:

```
fromDM k expr = case expr of
    Tuple es -> do
        x  <- generateNameM
        t' <- k x
        letExprs x t' es

letExprs x t' [e1, e2] = fromDM (\z1 -> fromDM (\z2 -> pure $ Let x [z1, z2] t') e2) e1
-- etc.
```

We would like to abstract `letExprs` so that it can work on lists of any length. Now that we've written down the problem, the next step in the Feynman protocol is to Think Very Hard. So I stared Very Hard at the different cases. It looked to me like each cons cell in the list turned into a call to `fromDM`; and in the base case, the `Let` was applied to a varying list. We can stick the varying list in an accumulator, like this:

```
fromDM k expr = case expr of
    Tuple es -> do
        x  <- generateNameM
        t' <- k x
        letExprs x t' [] es

letExprs x t' vars [] = pure $ Let x (reverse vars) t'
letExprs x t' vars (e:es) = fromDM (\z -> letExprs x t' (z:vars) es) e
```

This already looks pretty good to me. If you want to turn it into a fold (which is nice for the usual reasons: you can't accidentally screw up the recursion pattern, and readers know you're not doing anything tricky), we can now almost read it off directly:

```
fromDM k expr = case expr of
    Tuple es -> do
        x  <- generateNameM
        t' <- k x
        foldr (\e k vars -> fromDM (\z -> k (z:vars)) e)
              (\vars -> pure $ Let x (reverse vars) t')
              es
```

Comment: Looks great; we could simplify a bit because `Expr` only ever has a single case, thus `fromDM k (Tuple es) = do ...`

Comment: @Yawar Presumably this is a reduction of a more complicated collection of data types, so I tried to maintain the original code style wherever I could.